# Django - How to implement a search box

Tags: django, graphene-django, search-box

I'm struggling to implement a search bar and could really do with a few suggestions on how it could be done. I'm quite a novice, so please bear with me. My difficulties lie more with the general understanding of what needs to be built than with a specific line of code and somehow that's making it even harder for me to find an answer.

In summary, I have:

Django Models:

- Recipe
- Tags (M2M with Recipe)
- Category (ForeignKey with Recipe)
- etc.

I've written Graphene schemas to query the database (Postgres) by Tags, Categories and numerous Recipe attributes (e.g.: Recipe name). You can filter the recipes displayed on the frontend with those queries, by clicking on e.g. a certain category name.

What I'd however also like to have, is a search box where a user can enter a keyword of their choice on the frontend, and get back all the recipes that have something matching that keyword.

I don't know what or how to build something like that. To my novice mind, it seems like a search box of that sort would essentially be a query where I don't know what the filter is in advance, i.e. "fresh" as an input could be a tag, category, part of a recipe name, etc... and I'd want all those matching results back - ideally without the search taking an exaggerated amount of time.

How should I go about building something like this? I've built the search box (React/Tailwind), so it's really all about what the backend needs to provide when a user types a keyword and clicks search.

Thank you for your help! :)

The following code shows my models -> The Recipe model is however quite large (not all code included), so any tips on how to keep the search speed down are also very appreciated.

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
..
..
..
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=512, default='')

    tags = models.ManyToManyField('tag.Tag')
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        'tag.Category',
        related_name='recipe_category',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
    )
..
..
..

class Tag(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Category(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Edit: Code added

Comment: could you post your models code here

Comment: Thanks - Relevant model code added

Comment: You might find Django Haystack is a good fit for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, based on the search term, you are trying to query the category table, tags table, and recipes table. here **icontains** is a Django-related ORM utility that is equivalent to ILIKE in SQL.

```
from django.db.models import Q

# in your mutation
search_term = "from your graphene mutation"
categories = Category.objects.filter(name__icontains=search_term).values_list(
    "id", flat=True
)
tags = Tag.objects.filter(name__icontains=search_term).values_list("id", flat=True)
# here the Q object is used to build multiple or conditions
# the final query as response to your frontend
recipies = Recipe.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=search_term) | Q(description__icontains=search_term) | Q(tags__in=tags) | Q(category__in=categories))
```

Notice the number of queries here, since we are querying multiple tables, the response could be slow depending on the size of the data in the database. By proper indexing on the database, you can easily overcome this, or you can even use something like full-text search engines like elastic search, etc.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a great way to do it. - Thanks also for the info regarding search speed - I'll add that requirement to my original post too

Comment: well, it's fairly fast enough. But I wouldn't recommend it if your data is huge and if it contains a lot of text fields. In case your data is huge. you could go for elasticsearch and index your data or you can cache some frequent queries in redis or memcache.

Comment: Thanks! Then that's what I'll try - The project's dataset isn't that large, so I'm assuming this will be fine and otherwise I'll shift my focus towards learning how to implement indexing/elastic search. Have a great day!